# Why do I got NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist error?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am newbee to Terraform world. I am following one tutorial,but I tried to implement AWS Provider Upgrade Guide [Upgrade4](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#s3-bucket-refactor).
Terraform apply gives me

```
│ Error: error creating S3 bucket ACL for kevindenotariis-simple-web-app-logs: NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
│   status code: 404, request id: W5K3YPKHMN8YA458, host id: fH5xGgvTn8JfprqbaCsVCS/ICirJdVcDS9GOo8R7TFshS+UquH/Xy1n0ZcSdLgrdbRqFp4wFKzQ=
│ 
│   with aws_s3_bucket_acl.simple-web-app-logs,
│   on s3.tf line 3, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "simple-web-app-logs":
│    3: resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "simple-web-app-logs" {
```

My s3.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "simple-web-app-logs" {
  bucket = "kevindenotariis-simple-web-app-logs"
  acl = "private"
}

# S3 Bucket storing jenkins user data

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "jenkins-config" {
  bucket = "kevindenotariis-jenkins-config"
  acl = "private"
}
```

From jenkins.tf,two relevent lines

```
  bucket-logs-name = aws_s3_bucket_acl.simple-web-app-logs.id
  bucket-config-name = aws_s3_bucket_acl.jenkins-config.id
```

I tried Terraform plan

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_s3_bucket_acl.jenkins-config will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "jenkins-config" {
      + acl    = "private"
      + bucket = "kevindenotariis-jenkins-config"
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + access_control_policy {
          + grant {
              + permission = (known after apply)

              + grantee {
                  + display_name  = (known after apply)
                  + email_address = (known after apply)
                  + id            = (known after apply)
                  + type          = (known after apply)
                  + uri           = (known after apply)
                }
            }

          + owner {
              + display_name = (known after apply)
              + id           = (known after apply)
            }
        }
    }

  # aws_s3_bucket_acl.simple-web-app-logs will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "simple-web-app-logs" {
      + acl    = "private"
      + bucket = "kevindenotariis-simple-web-app-logs"
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + access_control_policy {
          + grant {
              + permission = (known after apply)

              + grantee {
                  + display_name  = (known after apply)
                  + email_address = (known after apply)
                  + id            = (known after apply)
                  + type          = (known after apply)
                  + uri           = (known after apply)
                }
            }

          + owner {
              + display_name = (known after apply)
              + id           = (known after apply)
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, the bucket does not exist. :) Can you verify in the AWS console that there is in fact a bucket with name `kevindenotariis-simple-web-app-logs`?

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED
By removing

```
acl = "private"
```

line

I reread again the above link, Terraform AWS Provider Version 4 Upgrade Guide.